# Spring Boot Application Context is not working

Tags: java, spring

Dependency Injection gives different results when using the Spring BeanFactory and ApplicationContext bean providers.

I am using the Triangle class:

```
public class Triangle {
  private String type;
  public String getType() {
    return type;
  }
  public void setType(String type) {
    this.type= type;
  }
  public void draw(){
    System.out.println(getName() + "Triangle")
  }
}
```

My main class is:

```
public class DrawingApp {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    BeanFactory factory = new XmlBeanFactory( new FileSystemResource("spring.xml"));
    Triangle triangle = (Triangle) factory.getBean("triangle");
    triangle.draw();

    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
    Triangle triangle1 = (Triangle) context.getBean("triangle");
    triangle1.draw();
  } 
}
```

And my spring.xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN 2.0//EN" 
 "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans-2.0.dtd">
   <beans> 
     <bean id = "triangle" class = "org.package.Triangle">
     <property name="type" value="equilateral"/>
   </bean>
 </beans>
```

The output should be:

```
equilateral triangle
equilateral triangle
```

but the output I get is:

```
equilateral triangle
null triangle
```

Comment: In which folder have you placed the spring.xml file? Seems like opening it as file or as resource is either not finding it or fingind different xml files. It should be under src/main/resources ..

Comment: In src/  (i.e class path)

Comment: Uhm, are you sure it is in the classpath? src/ is not usually directly included in it; src/main/resources is

Comment: this won't compile, you're redeclaring the `triangle`variable.

Comment: @P.J.Meisch , he's copy-pasting, it also won't set the "type" property since the setter is "setName"

Comment: Edited the code

Comment: @Daniele It's a eclipse project I only have src/ folder

Comment: Right- well maybe you edited the file under "target"? Check the answer below- basically, check if you indeed have *two* different config files-